# Explain surprising number of timers and finding their origin

Tags: memory-leaks, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a CPU leak somewhere and am trying to find out the origin (the RAM increases a bit too but not as fast).

I have collected some data through `dotnet-counters` and found out that the number of timers in the given process keeps increasing. For instance, when 46 % of the CPU was used, it was reporting around 450 timers (see following data). Note that this count only increases, slowly but surely like my CPU usage. And also note that it's pretty much at a time where it was idle, not having customers online.

[image]

This leads to 2 questions:

1) Is it normal? Should I continue on this track? I find it odd to have this many timers.

2) In my own code, I never user the Timer class, I use the Stopwatch class once but that's it.

So what would be the best way to find the class/library that uses those timers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) There was indeed something fishy and it is definitely not normal.

I had a class spawning hundreds of threads and keeping them alive to listen to incoming calls.

Long story short, that many timers is not something normal.

2) The Timer was coming from somewhere deep in a library. I couldn't find an easy way to find them.

Best option is to use dotnet-trace collect. https://www.speedscope.app/ helped me a lot and it is possible to generate de traces for speedscope directly from dotnet-trace.